# SSM Parameter store - how to dynamically select version of parameter I need to access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am using SSM Secure Parameter store to store a password for an RDS DB.

- I have CloudFormation that

  - Generates the password and stores it under a key with a specific name.  The name is generated based one of the input parameters to the CloudFormation
  - The parameter is stored using an IAM role created by the CloudFormation
- Another CloudFormation stack that runs after

  - Uses the same IAM role to retrieve the parameters and deploy RDS using the parameter as the password
  - That CloudFormation uses `ssm-secure:` like this

```
            "MasterUserPassword": {
                "Fn::Sub": "{{resolve:ssm-secure:${WorkshopName}:1}}"
            },
```

Note the "1".  The [SSM Secure String Parameters docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html) are very clear:  *An integer that specifies the version of the parameter to use. You must specify the exact version. You cannot currently specify that AWS CloudFormation use the latest version of a parameter*

That's the bummer

- Using the latest version is exactly what I want to do
- Under some circumstances I can end up with an old key in the version 1 slot.  Then everything fails as the first CFN stack creates v2, and the next stack tries to retrieve v1 and fails (it was created under a different IAM Role and fails with `The ciphertext refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access.`)

Any programmatic suggestion on how I might implement more resilient logic to either

- always grab the latest version, or
- catch failures when it tries to get v1, and then increment versions until is succeeds

Comment: Have you considered [using AWS Secrets Manager for storing and rotating Amazon RDS passwords](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/integrating_cloudformation.html)? It specifically knows how to work with RDS.

Comment: Or perhaps you could create a custom resource that gets the latest version and returns it as an output to the stack for later use. (I have not tested this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks [here like the behavior has changed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html):

> version
>
> An integer that specifies the version of the parameter to use.
> If you don't specify the exact version, CloudFormation uses the latest
> version of the parameter whenever you create or update the stack. For
> more information, see Working with parameter versions in the AWS
> Systems Manager User Guide
>
> Optional.

So now it can access the latest version